# No interfaces detected apart from loopback in OpenWRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt, embedded-linux

Installed OpenWRT in laptop Dell Latitude E5550,

Booted up using live Ubuntu DVD and issued following commands.

```
$ wget https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/openwrt-15.05-x86-generic-combined-ext4.img.gz
$ gunzip openwrt-15.05-x86-generic-combined-ext4.img.gz
$ dd if=openwrt-15.05-x86-generic-combined-ext4.img of=/dev/sda
```

Rebooted the system, when I check the interfaces using

```
$ifconfig
```

Apart from my loopback adapter, the installed OpenWRT OS is unable to detect the rest of my interfaces which are

```
eth0 & wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into this, may help.
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/vmware,
adding

`ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"`

to `.vmx` file solve my problem

Comment: This isn’t about running OpenWrt in a virtual machine.